# WooCommerce: resetting a single attribute in a variable product

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Each product has 2 attributes involved in variations - color and size. For all products in the categories, the add to cart button is hidden, and the product is added to the cart when the size is clicked. That is, a person selects a color, clicks on the desired size, and the product falls into the basket. It works.

I need to reset the "Size" attribute after adding the product to the cart, while not resetting the selected "Color" attribute. Right now, with jQuery, I'm resetting all the parameters with a hidden link.

Here's what we have now:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#product_list').on('click', '.pa_size li.variable-item', function(){
        let productWrap = $(this).closest('.product_item');

        setTimeout(function(){
            productWrap.find('button.single_add_to_cart_button').click();
        }, 500);
    
        setTimeout(function(){
            productWrap.find('a.reset_variations').click();
        }, 600);
    });
});
```

Here I click on the hidden add to cart button after the buyer clicked on the "Size" attribute, and then click on the hidden "Clear attributes" link. This works, but need to leave the "Color" as it is, do not reset it.

```
<div class="jet-listing-grid__item jet-listing-dynamic-post-704 jet-equal-columns" data-post-id="704">
    <div data-elementor-type="jet-listing-items" data-elementor-id="102" class="elementor elementor-102" data-elementor-settings="[]">
        <div class="elementor-section-wrap">
            <section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-77ec41c elementor-section-full_width product_item elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="77ec41c" data-element_type="section">
                <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-2457e90" data-id="2457e90" data-element_type="column">
                        <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-6663cd9 elementor-widget elementor-widget-shortcode" data-id="6663cd9" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="shortcode.default">
                                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                    <div class="woo-product-variation-gallery">
                                        <div class="woo-product-single-variation selected"><img src="https://wordpress-demo.ru/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/040f0green.jpg" data-size="36" data-color="zelenyj"></div>

                                        <div class="woo-product-single-variation "><img src="https://wordpress-demo.ru/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/040f0ochra.jpg" data-size="38" data-color="ohra"></div>

                                        <div class="woo-product-single-variation "><img src="https://wordpress-demo.ru/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/040f0white.jpg" data-size="36" data-color="belyj"></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="elementor-shortcode"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-a958452 elementor-section-full_width elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="a958452" data-element_type="section">
                                <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-50 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-5555553" data-id="5555553" data-element_type="column">
                                        <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-8ae8315 elementor-widget__width-auto elementor-widget elementor-widget-jet-listing-dynamic-field" data-id="8ae8315" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="jet-listing-dynamic-field.default">
                                                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                                    <div class="jet-listing jet-listing-dynamic-field display-inline">
                                                        <div class="jet-listing-dynamic-field__inline-wrap">
                                                            <div class="jet-listing-dynamic-field__content">
                                                                040F0
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-cd5e7d9 elementor-widget__width-auto elementor-widget elementor-widget-jet-listing-dynamic-link" data-id="cd5e7d9" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="jet-listing-dynamic-link.default">
                                                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                                    <div class="jet-listing jet-listing-dynamic-link">
                                                        <a href="https://wordpress-demo.ru/product/bluza-flaibach-2/" class="jet-listing-dynamic-link__link"><span class="jet-listing-dynamic-link__label">Блуза flaibach</span></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-50 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-28b820c" data-id="28b820c" data-element_type="column">
                                        <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-2486370 elementor-widget elementor-widget-jet-wishlist-button" data-id="2486370" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="jet-wishlist-button.default">
                                                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                                    <div class="jet-wishlist-button jet-cw">
                                                        <div class="jet-wishlist-button__container">
                                                            <a href="#" class="jet-wishlist-button__link jet-wishlist-button__link--icon-top" data-widget-type="jet-wishlist-button" data-product-id="704" data-widget-id="2486370"></a>

                                                            <div class="jet-wishlist-button__plane jet-wishlist-button__plane-normal"></div>

                                                            <div class="jet-wishlist-button__plane jet-wishlist-button__plane-added"></div>

                                                            <div class="jet-wishlist-button__state jet-wishlist-button__state-normal"></div>

                                                            <div class="jet-wishlist-button__state jet-wishlist-button__state-added"></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </section>

                            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-52f3455 elementor-widget elementor-widget-spacer" data-id="52f3455" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="spacer.default">
                                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                    <div class="elementor-spacer">
                                        <div class="elementor-spacer-inner"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-e2b61d1 elementor-widget elementor-widget-jet-woo-builder-archive-product-price" data-id="e2b61d1" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="jet-woo-builder-archive-product-price.default">
                                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                    <div class="jet-woo-builder-archive-product-price">
                                        <div class="jet-woo-product-price">
                                            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">2.384&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₽</span></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-d9aab95 elementor-widget elementor-widget-spacer" data-id="d9aab95" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="spacer.default">
                                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                    <div class="elementor-spacer">
                                        <div class="elementor-spacer-inner"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-781c075 first_add_cart elementor-widget elementor-widget-jet-woo-builder-archive-add-to-cart" data-id="781c075" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="jet-woo-builder-archive-add-to-cart.default">
                                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                    <div class="elementor-jet-woo-builder-archive-add-to-cart jet-woo-builder">
                                        <div class="jet-woo-builder-archive-add-to-cart" data-cart-popup-enable="false" data-cart-popup-id="">
                                            <form class="variations_form cart wvs-loaded wvs-pro-loaded" action="https://wordpress-demo.ru/product/bluza-flaibach-2/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="704" data-product_variations="[{"attributes":{"attribute_pa_size":"36","attribute_pa_color":"zelenyj"},"availability_html":"<p class=\"stock in-stock\">1 \u0432 \u043d\u0430\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0438\u0438<\/p>\n","backorders_allowed":false,"dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":""},"dimensions_html":"\u041d\/\u0414","display_price":2384,"display_regular_price":2384,"image":{"title":"040f0green.jpg","caption":"","url":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0green.jpg","alt":"","src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0green.jpg","srcset":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0green.jpg 1000w, https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0green-768x1152.jpg 768w","sizes":"(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px","full_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0green.jpg","full_src_w":1000,"full_src_h":1500,"gallery_thumbnail_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0green-300x300.jpg","gallery_thumbnail_src_w":100,"gallery_thumbnail_src_h":100,"thumb_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0green-300x300.jpg","thumb_src_w":300,"thumb_src_h":300,"src_w":600,"src_h":900,"thumb_srcset":false,"thumb_sizes":"(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"},"image_id":320,"is_downloadable":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_purchasable":true,"is_sold_individually":"no","is_virtual":false,"max_qty":1,"min_qty":1,"price_html":"","sku":"040F0-36-1\n","variation_description":"","variation_id":721,"variation_is_active":true,"variation_is_visible":true,"weight":"","weight_html":"\u041d\/\u0414","variation_gallery_images":[{"image_id":320,"title":"040f0green.jpg","caption":"","url":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0green.jpg","alt":"","full_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0green.jpg","full_src_w":"1000","full_src_h":"1500","full_class":"attachment-full size-full","gallery_thumbnail_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0green-300x300.jpg","gallery_thumbnail_src_w":"100","gallery_thumbnail_src_h":"100","gallery_thumbnail_class":"attachment-100x100 size-100x100","archive_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0green-300x300.jpg","archive_src_w":"300","archive_src_h":"300","archive_class":"attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail","src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0green.jpg","class":"wp-post-image wvg-post-image attachment-woocommerce_single size-woocommerce_single ","src_w":"600","src_h":"900","srcset":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0green.jpg 1000w, https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0green-768x1152.jpg 768w","sizes":"(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px","extra_params":"","video_link":""}]},{"attributes":{"attribute_pa_size":"38","attribute_pa_color":"ohra"},"availability_html":"<p class=\"stock in-stock\">2 \u0432 \u043d\u0430\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0438\u0438<\/p>\n","backorders_allowed":false,"dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":""},"dimensions_html":"\u041d\/\u0414","display_price":2384,"display_regular_price":2384,"image":{"title":"040f0ochra.jpg","caption":"","url":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0ochra.jpg","alt":"","src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0ochra.jpg","srcset":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0ochra.jpg 1000w, https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0ochra-768x1152.jpg 768w","sizes":"(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px","full_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0ochra.jpg","full_src_w":1000,"full_src_h":1500,"gallery_thumbnail_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0ochra-300x300.jpg","gallery_thumbnail_src_w":100,"gallery_thumbnail_src_h":100,"thumb_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0ochra-300x300.jpg","thumb_src_w":300,"thumb_src_h":300,"src_w":600,"src_h":900,"thumb_srcset":false,"thumb_sizes":"(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"},"image_id":323,"is_downloadable":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_purchasable":true,"is_sold_individually":"no","is_virtual":false,"max_qty":2,"min_qty":1,"price_html":"","sku":"040F0-38-1\n","variation_description":"","variation_id":722,"variation_is_active":true,"variation_is_visible":true,"weight":"","weight_html":"\u041d\/\u0414","variation_gallery_images":[{"image_id":323,"title":"040f0ochra.jpg","caption":"","url":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0ochra.jpg","alt":"","full_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0ochra.jpg","full_src_w":"1000","full_src_h":"1500","full_class":"attachment-full size-full","gallery_thumbnail_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0ochra-300x300.jpg","gallery_thumbnail_src_w":"100","gallery_thumbnail_src_h":"100","gallery_thumbnail_class":"attachment-100x100 size-100x100","archive_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0ochra-300x300.jpg","archive_src_w":"300","archive_src_h":"300","archive_class":"attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail","src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0ochra.jpg","class":"wp-post-image wvg-post-image attachment-woocommerce_single size-woocommerce_single ","src_w":"600","src_h":"900","srcset":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0ochra.jpg 1000w, https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0ochra-768x1152.jpg 768w","sizes":"(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px","extra_params":"","video_link":""}]},{"attributes":{"attribute_pa_size":"36","attribute_pa_color":"belyj"},"availability_html":"<p class=\"stock in-stock\">3 \u0432 \u043d\u0430\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0438\u0438<\/p>\n","backorders_allowed":false,"dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":""},"dimensions_html":"\u041d\/\u0414","display_price":2384,"display_regular_price":2384,"image":{"title":"040f0white.jpg","caption":"","url":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white.jpg","alt":"","src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white.jpg","srcset":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white.jpg 1000w, https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white-768x1152.jpg 768w","sizes":"(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px","full_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white.jpg","full_src_w":1000,"full_src_h":1500,"gallery_thumbnail_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white-300x300.jpg","gallery_thumbnail_src_w":100,"gallery_thumbnail_src_h":100,"thumb_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white-300x300.jpg","thumb_src_w":300,"thumb_src_h":300,"src_w":600,"src_h":900,"thumb_srcset":false,"thumb_sizes":"(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"},"image_id":325,"is_downloadable":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_purchasable":true,"is_sold_individually":"no","is_virtual":false,"max_qty":3,"min_qty":1,"price_html":"","sku":"040F0-36-2\n","variation_description":"","variation_id":723,"variation_is_active":true,"variation_is_visible":true,"weight":"","weight_html":"\u041d\/\u0414","variation_gallery_images":[{"image_id":325,"title":"040f0white.jpg","caption":"","url":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white.jpg","alt":"","full_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white.jpg","full_src_w":"1000","full_src_h":"1500","full_class":"attachment-full size-full","gallery_thumbnail_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white-300x300.jpg","gallery_thumbnail_src_w":"100","gallery_thumbnail_src_h":"100","gallery_thumbnail_class":"attachment-100x100 size-100x100","archive_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white-300x300.jpg","archive_src_w":"300","archive_src_h":"300","archive_class":"attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail","src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white.jpg","class":"wp-post-image wvg-post-image attachment-woocommerce_single size-woocommerce_single ","src_w":"600","src_h":"900","srcset":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white.jpg 1000w, https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white-768x1152.jpg 768w","sizes":"(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px","extra_params":"","video_link":""},{"image_id":327,"title":"040f0white_.jpg","caption":"","url":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white_.jpg","alt":"","full_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white_.jpg","full_src_w":"1000","full_src_h":"1500","full_class":"attachment-full size-full","gallery_thumbnail_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white_-300x300.jpg","gallery_thumbnail_src_w":"100","gallery_thumbnail_src_h":"100","gallery_thumbnail_class":"attachment-100x100 size-100x100","archive_src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white_-300x300.jpg","archive_src_w":"300","archive_src_h":"300","archive_class":"attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail","src":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white_.jpg","class":"wp-post-image wvg-post-image attachment-woocommerce_single size-woocommerce_single ","src_w":"600","src_h":"900","srcset":"https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white_.jpg 1000w, https:\/\/wordpress-demo.ru\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/03\/040f0white_-768x1152.jpg 768w","sizes":"(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px","extra_params":"","video_link":""}]}]" current-image="">
                                                <div class="variations">
                                                    <div class="pa_size">
                                                        <span class="value woo-variation-items-wrapper"><select id="pa_size" class=" hide woo-variation-raw-select woo-variation-raw-type-button" style="display:none" name="attribute_pa_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_size" data-show_option_none="yes">
                                                            <option value="">
                                                                Выбрать опцию
                                                            </option>

                                                            <option value="36" class="attached enabled">
                                                                36
                                                            </option>
                                                        </select></span>

                                                        <ul role="radiogroup" aria-label="Размер" class="variable-items-wrapper button-variable-wrapper" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_size" data-attribute_values="[">
                                                            <li aria-checked="false" data-wvstooltip="36" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-36" data-title="36" title="36" data-value="36" role="radio" tabindex="0">
                                                                <div class="variable-item-contents">
                                                                    <span class="value woo-variation-items-wrapper"><span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">36</span></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </li>

                                                            <li aria-checked="false" data-wvstooltip="38" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-38 disabled" data-title="38" title="38" data-value="38" role="radio" tabindex="-1">
                                                                <div class="variable-item-contents">
                                                                    <span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">38</span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="pa_color">
                                                        <span class="value woo-variation-items-wrapper"><select id="pa_color" class=" hide woo-variation-raw-select woo-variation-raw-type-color" style="display:none" name="attribute_pa_color" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_color" data-show_option_none="yes">
                                                            <option value="">
                                                                Выбрать опцию
                                                            </option>

                                                            <option value="ohra" class="attached enabled">
                                                                Охра
                                                            </option>

                                                            <option value="belyj" class="attached enabled">
                                                                Белый
                                                            </option>

                                                            <option value="zelenyj" selected="selected" class="attached enabled">
                                                                Зеленый
                                                            </option>
                                                        </select></span>

                                                        <ul role="radiogroup" aria-label="Цвет" class="variable-items-wrapper color-variable-wrapper" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_color" data-attribute_values="[">
                                                            <li aria-checked="false" data-wvstooltip="Охра" class="variable-item color-variable-item color-variable-item-ohra" data-title="Охра" title="Охра" data-value="ohra" role="radio" tabindex="0">
                                                                <div class="variable-item-contents"></div>
                                                            </li>

                                                            <li aria-checked="false" data-wvstooltip="Белый" class="variable-item color-variable-item color-variable-item-belyj" data-title="Белый" title="Белый" data-value="belyj" role="radio" tabindex="0">
                                                                <div class="variable-item-contents"></div>
                                                            </li>

                                                            <li aria-checked="true" data-wvstooltip="Зеленый" class="variable-item color-variable-item color-variable-item-zelenyj selected" data-title="Зеленый" title="Зеленый" data-value="zelenyj" role="radio" tabindex="0">
                                                                <div class="variable-item-contents"></div>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul><a class="reset_variations" href="#">Очистить</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="single_variation_wrap">
                                                    <div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation" style="display: none;"></div>

                                                    <div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled">
                                                        <div class="qib-container">
                                                            <button type="button" class="minus qib-button">-</button>

                                                            <div class="quantity buttons_added">
                                                                <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_604f4040e0474">Количество Блуза flaibach</label> <input type="number" id="quantity_604f4040e0474" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол-во" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric">
                                                            </div><button type="button" class="plus qib-button">+</button>
                                                        </div><button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt disabled wc-variation-selection-needed">В корзину</button> <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="704"> <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="704"> <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The current version is on the page https://wordpress-demo.ru/shop/

I would be grateful for any hint.

Comment: Your variable product seems something custom made by yourself or a plugin… Nobody can guess how is the html structure where your jQuery code is acting… You should provide some minimal html structure in your question. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I understand, thanks for the correction. I supplemented the post with what I know, and also added a link to the page I'm working on.